# How to empty Heroku db and repopulate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

I have seen some of the answers to this question but none seem to work for me.
I accidently ran `heroku run rake db:seed` twice. And so have double date in my db.
So I want to drop the table, remigrate and run seed again (once this time ;) )
The Solutions I have seen so far tell me to run: `heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE` or `heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE --confirm <myAppName>`. Both of which don't work. The error I get is this:

```
    heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/pg_resolver.rb:125:in `parse_config': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/pg_resolver.rb:116:in `parse_config'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/pg_resolver.rb:79:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/pg_resolver.rb:34:in `new'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/pg_resolver.rb:34:in `resolve_db'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:70:in `reset'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:114:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/heroku-2.8.0/bin/heroku:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

All I want to do is be able to drop the table and then repopulate it with my seed data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `heroku pg:reset` is the correct command, but you have an old version of the gem, you might want to upgrade. Also, with the latest Postgres stack, the SHARED_DATABASE config variable does not exist - the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) says that the command should be `heroku pg:reset DATABASE`.

Comment: Yes I had tried the pg:reset command with DATABASE as well, which resulted in the same error. It could well be, that the gem I am using is out of date, but since it is tied to an online class I will stick with it, to have the same system as the testing environment. As mentioned above I have gotten it to work with `heroku run rake db:rollback`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply go into the heroku console and delete the seed data.

```
heroku run console
```

And delete all the items in the table.

Comment: yes I could do that. For that matter the seed data wasn't that large, so I could just use the webinterface to delete the duplicates. But in general it would be nice to know for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which seems to work. With `heroku run rake db:rollback` I was able to drop the table, and then migrate and reseed the data.
Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The way I get the name of the database variable from Heroku is by running `heroku config | grep POSTGRESQL`. This will output the name of the variable and its URL. You can then drop the database by going `heroku pg:reset <DATABASE>` (which might be `heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL_URL`, for instance). You should then be able to migrate the database again and populate it however you do ordinarily.